MATLAB variable appears to change size on every loop iteration when final size in unknow
I am coding in MATLAB.
I encountered this warning: "Variable appears to change size on every loop iteration".
Unfortunately, I cannot know in advance the size of that variable, so I cannot preallocate it.
Is there a way to silence this annoying warning?
Thanks.
This is the code I executed:
removed = [] ;
while condition
    [...]
    removed = [ removed, worst ] ;
end
disp(removed) ;

Unfortunately I cannot allocate it like:
removed = NaN( 1, dimension ) ;

It would be great to remove this warning without changing the logic of the algorithm, since the final size of removed is expected to be very small.

You have really two solutions here:

Rewrite your code to not increase the array size. The general recommended strategy is to allocate an array that is large enough to fit any result (“over-allocate”), then trim it after the loop.
Suppress the warning by right-clicking on the underlined code and selecting “suppress ‘…’” (the warning title is included in the menu option). This will add a comment %#ok<…> at the end of the line of code. See the documentation.

If you go with the second option, I recommend that you rewrite removed = [removed, worst] as removed(end+1) = worst, as that is a lot more efficient, see this Q&A.
